# Galois group of certain quartic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose we have a quartic irreducible $x^4+ax^2+b\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

We wee that its roots are symmetric in origin: $\alpha\mapsto -\alpha$ is an automorphism of the roots, so it is a member of the Galois group of the polynomial.

Since this antipodal map commutes with every permutation of roots, i.e. it is an automorphism of order $2$ commuting with every automorphism of the roots in the Galois group, can we conclude that Galois group of the polynomial can not be $A_4$ or $S_4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can construct the splitting field of $f=X^4+aX^2+b$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\xi,\sqrt{\xi},\sqrt{-a-\xi})$, where $\xi$ is a zero of $g=X^2+aX+b$. So it is of degree $4$ or $8$ (it can't be any less since $f$ is irreducible), which means that the Galois group is $C_4$, $V_4$, or $D_4$ (all these cases can occur), and in particular is not $A_4$ or $S_4$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known classification of Galois groups of polynomials of degree 4, using the discriminant of the polynomial and its resolvent cubic.

If you compute the resolvent cubic of $f$ you will see that has no independent coefficient, so its irreducible. So depending on the discriminant, the Galois group could be $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, or $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ or $D_{4}$.